# OSX web sharing memcached php

Tags: php, macos, memcached

I've been using the web sharing feature of my Mac to test some php code.

I have some code I run on ubuntu machines that uses memcached.  Now I would like to test it locally using web sharing.

To install the memcached extension for ubuntu I do this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-memcached
```

How can I get the extension installed on the OSX's default web sharing setup so I can test my code locally?

Comment: this gawna get clooo-ooosed, so-fast.

Comment: why? it's a valid question and no one has answered it yet...

Answer (score 2):

You can install memcached using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package manager for os x `brew install memcached`.

Once installed to get it working you will need a few additional steps which are detailed by brew when you do the install or with `brew info memcached`.

Brew is awesome!

You can install the php extension with brew too! To enable it in php you will have to modify the php.ini file and add the extension. something like :

```
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/__packagename__/__version__/memcached.so"
```

Comment: thanks, I had done that already, but that's how to install memcached, not how to install the php extension for web sharing's php

Comment: I've added a bit more to my answer

Comment: thanks, but where is the correct php.ini for the default installation of web sharing?  i have /etc/php.ini.default but not /etc/php.ini What is web sharing using?

Comment: also /usr/local/Cellar/memcached-php/__version__/memcached.so doesn't exist, i have /usr/local/Cellar/memcached/ and brew install memcached-php is not a formula

Comment: when i run php --ini it says /etc/ but like i say all i have there is php.ini.default

Comment: brew search memcache shows a list of packages. memached-php used to be there but I can't see it. I do see what looks like alternative packages such as josegonzalez/php/php54-memcached.